# Creating circle legend around map using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, legend, layouts

I saw following picture in an article. I want to create a map like this for my datasets with that circle legend around it.

How can I create that circle legend around that map visualizing 30 polygons on the map by using ArcMap 10.7?

[image]

Comment: It is not a good practice in this site to delete a former closed question and asking it again. You should edit your previous question for reopening it.

Comment: Thank you xunilk

Comment: You're welcome. As repeated practice, this behavior could be considered spam and your count closed.

Comment: I don't think there's a straightforward way to do this. You would somehow have to calculate the shape of those boxes, and add them to the page layout. Not impossible, but it would require some programming. Maybe it would be easier to do in a graphics application? You should also ask yourself if this is really the best way to represent the data. Other than looking nice, it isn't very readable in my opinion. Why not include the boxes in the area list on the left? That way, you don't need to look up the numbers.

Comment: It's easy enough to generate a polygon layer in the needed format (two buffers and a pie slice, unioned), attribute it, and draw, but as a cartography technique, it just uses too much space -- you could make the map 30% larger!